# Need help getting Invoke-Sqlcmd, -InputFile & -Variable working nicely together

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I have `File1.ps1` containing the command as follows:

```
$VariableArray = "PrincipleName='Jack'"

Invoke-Sqlcmd -InputFile "C:\Amit\Test.sql" `
    -Variable $VariableArray `
    -ServerInstance "3STOOGES"
```

my `Test.sql` contains

```
    declare @PrincipleName varchar(20)
    SELECT 'PrincipleName=' + @PrincipleName
```

This gives me output as

```
Column1
-------
```

I tried something mentioned [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/d0b9c410-27f5-45ce-9bfa-57013ec2878c/sqlps-need-help-getting-invokesqlcmd-inputfile-variable-working-nicely-together?forum=sqltools)

I tried the options for `$(PrincipleName)` inside the `Test.sql`, but it complained the SQL server Management Studio.

Please advise as I Have SQL server 2012 with Powershell 3.0 on Windows 2012

Comment: You're setting a variable called EmpName but then referencing @PrincipleName in the SQL file.  Not sure how that is going to work. Try changing EmpName to PrincipleName.

Comment: I corrected it to PrincipleName in the ps1 file.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax is all wrong.  SELECT @PrincipleName will just return nothing since variable is not set.

Use this syntax in a powershell ISE.

```
Import-Module “sqlps” -DisableNameChecking
$MyArray = "MyVar1 = 'String1'", "MyVar2 = 'String2'"
Invoke-Sqlcmd -InputFile "C:\temp\john.sql" -Variable $MyArray
```

Use this syntax in the sql file.

```
SELECT $(MyVar1) AS Var1, $(MyVar2) AS Var2;
```

The output is shown here and works correctly.

[image]