# Can run SQL file from PowerShell with multiple parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell

I have a PowerShell script the with get data and then run a SQL file, parsing in the data it have got. However I keep getting the following error:

> Invoke-Sqlcmd : The format used to define the new variable for Invoke-Sqlcmd cmdlet is invalid. Please use the 'var=value' format for defining a new variable.

**PowerShell Script:**

```
Write-host $ID, $XMLParam, $SourceID

$DBParam1 = "ID="+ $ID
$DBParam2 = "XMLPARAM="+ $XMLParam
$DBParam3 = "SOURCEID="+ $SourceID

$DBParams = @($DBParam1, $DBParam2, $DBParam3)

$Results = Invoke-Sqlcmd -InputFile "D:\SamHelp\marksheet.sql" -Variable $DBParams -Server $SQLServer -Database 'DB' -Username $Username -Password $Password
```

**SQL File:**

```
declare @id int, @xmlParam xml, @sourceID int

SET @id = '$(ID)'
SET @xmlParam =  '$(XMLPARAM)'
SET @sourceID = '$(SOURCEID)'
...
```

The `Write-Host` in the powershell outputs:

`001 <data><destSu id="000001"/><destSu id="000002"/></data> 0000001`

Comment: Can't test this (hence not posted as answer) but based on examples from other related questions (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16654866/invoke-sqlcmd-inputfile-and-variable and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19283531/need-help-getting-invoke-sqlcmd-inputfile-variable-working-nicely-together) I think you might need to place single quotes around the parameter values (at least the XML one anyway, since it's a string), e.g. `$DBParam2 = "XMLPARAM='"+ $XMLParam + "'"` . Not sure if you'll need to do it for the other two or not, since they're numeric

Comment: If $XMLParam is a string containing XML with double quotes, another thing you can try if the suggestion @ADyson provided doesn't work is `$DBParam2 = "XMLPARAM="+ $XMLParam.Replace('"', '""')`. This will escape the double quotes in the SQLCMD scripting variable value.